# return number in functions

Tags: python, function

First, def a function called cube that takes an argument called number. Don't forget the parentheses and the colon!
Make that function return the cube of that number (i.e. that number multiplied by itself and multiplied by itself once again).
Define a second function called by_three that takes an argument called number.
if that number is divisible by 3, by_three should call cube(number) and return its result. Otherwise, by_three should return False.

```
def cube(number):
    return number**3
def by_three(number):
    if number%3==0:
        cube(3)
        return number
    else:
        return False
```

what is the mistake in this pls answer. it is showing Oops, try again. by_three(3) returned 3 instead of 27

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should post your code here, in a code block, instead of a link to an image.

Comment: As it says, line 5's indentation is not in line with the line above it (or below it)

Comment: @Obsidian I'd say all the lines, starting form the 5th, are not properly indented

Comment: can u pls explain me clearly i cant understand

Comment: @GauravKochar You should edit your post and paste the code there

Comment: @bastelflp i have written like that only why it is not coming

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: i have made the changes now indention mistake has gone but answer is wrong it is showing see the  task and see wat change should i make

Answer (score 1):

This is your solution.

```
def cube(number):
    return number ** 3

def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        return cube(number)
    else:
        return False
```

Also the `by_three` function can be even shorter

```
def by_three(number):
    return cube(number) if number % 3 == 0 else False
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong. You need to put `cube(9)` like this:

```
if number%3 == 0:
    cube(9)
```

And you probably want to return the result of `cube()`, not the original `number`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your indentation to this:

```
def cube(number):
    return number ** 3
def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        cube(9)        
        return number
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is indent cube(9). This is because it's under an if statement.

```
def cube(number):
    return number ** 3
def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        cube(9)        
        return number
    else:
        return False
```